# How can I simplify disable/enable control angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a lot of functions like:

```
changeScondPlace(event) {
    if(event.checked == false) {
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2longer'].disable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2'].disable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2days'].disable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationstart'].disable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationend'].disable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2placement'].disable();
    } else {
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2longer'].enable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2'].enable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2days'].enable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationstart'].enable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationend'].enable();
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2placement'].enable();
    }
  }
```

This function will change inputs state from disable to enable or from enable to disable by clicking on checkbox.

I've tried

```
 this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2longer'].enable = event.checked;
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2'].enable = event.checked;
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2days'].enable = event.checked;
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationstart'].enable = event.checked;
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationend'].enable = event.checked;
      this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2placement'].enable = event.checked;
```

Guys is there a way to simplify that code?

Comment: Have you tried to disable formGroup?

Answer (score 1):

```
changeScondPlace(event) {
if(event.checked == false) {
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2longer'].disable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2'].disable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2days'].disable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationstart'].disable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationend'].disable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2placement'].disable();
} else {
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2longer'].enable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2'].enable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2days'].enable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationstart'].enable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['picker2locationend'].enable();
  this.GeofencingSection.controls['location2placement'].enable();
}
```

}

If these are all the fields in you form, you may simply try:

```
this.GeofencingSection.disable();
```

and
this.GeofencingSection.enable();

If these elements are not the only elements in your form and there are other elements as well, perhaps you can put these controls into a group in the `this.GeofencingSection` object. In that case, if your group name is "someGroup", you would need to do:

```
this.GeofencingSection.controls['someGroup'].disable();
```

and
this.GeofencingSection.controls['someGroup'].enable();
All the form controls under the group will be disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If GeofencingSection is an Angular [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) you should be able to [disable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable) it in all one go

```
 this.GeofencingSection.disable();
```

And to turn it back on

```
 this.GeofencingSection.enable();
```

So you could write it as

```
changeScondPlace = (event) => event.checked ? this.GeofencingStation.enable() : this.GeofencingStation.disable();
```